# Display looped data in Div with css style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i following code in jsp, where ModelData is List< Entry< String, Integer>>

```
<div style="width:20px; float:left";>
<c:forEach items="${ModelData}" var="map">
    <c:forEach items="${map.value}" var="entry"> 
       <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>  
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

above code displays like this:

```
word1: 123
word2: 122
word3: 108
word4: 78
word5: 60
word6: 50
word7: 50
word8: 45
word9: 45
word10: 8
```

but i want it to display like below, with max of 4 columns, and min of 5 rows.

```
word1: 123   word4: 78  word7: 50  word10: 8
word2: 122   word5: 60  word8: 45
word3: 108   word6: 50  word9: 45
```

This has to get adjust its height and depending on items in loop.

How could i do this.Please help me on this.

here i have like this structure

```
<div>
 <div>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div>
 --my shown code here --
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
height: 100px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div>
word1: 123
</div>
<div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div><div>
word1: 123
</div>
```

Try this CSS:

```
height: 100px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Apply this css to parent element.

```
flex-basis: 33.33%;
```

Apply this css to child element.

Comment: You can also add `flex-basis: 20%` to child elements so that there are always 5 rows (provided the height of the parent div is large enough to fit them). But I don't think it's possible just with CSS to ensure a min of 5 rows and max of 4 columns. You'd need to know how many children there are to do that.

Comment: @Swapnil Patil This css display data continuosly one after the other. It has to look like arrangeg in table like. with words left aligned as shown in example.

Comment: check snippet @daisy

Comment: @Swapnil Patil Look at edited question, in there i have shown structure of my jsp design.  In there which is parent and child?

Comment: Can you provide me fiddle? @daisy

Comment: @Swapnil Patil  Sorry for delay response. Here is HTML code used in jsp  https://jsfiddle.net/bbjk/d8cjz8hh/

Comment: Instead of body apply css to div.row and it will work @daisy

Comment: @Swapnil Patil i am not able to fix width, it come out of margin. i used width=250px; in style.

Comment: In your fiddle put static data. i ll check it. @daisy

Comment: @Swapnil Patil i think you can put width in your given example code, by adding width =100px.